# PHP manipulate string (find/replace if component present)

Tags: php, string, query-string, text-manipulation

I need to check a string using PHP for a particular text component and replace the value if it is present with a new value. For example I might have a string like this:

```
?customerID=12345&recid=65&skip=20&type=job
```

I need to locate the "&skip=20" (it won't always = 20, it could be any number like 20, 80, 100, etc) substring and replace the "20" value with a new value from a variable ($newValue). So if that string was present and $newValue = 40 the new string would be:

```
?customerID=12345&recid=65&skip=40&type=job
```

If the string was:

```
?customerID=12345&recid=65&skip=160&type=job
```

the new string would be ($newValue = 180):

```
?customerID=12345&recid=65&skip=180&type=job
```

I'm pretty sure I should be using these functions -  strpos, preg_match, preg_replace - but I've spent way too long on this and don't appear to be getting any closer. If anyone can show me how to use these or other functions to find the substring and replace the value that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [`parse_str`](http://us.php.net/parse_str) and [`http_build_query`](http://us.php.net/http_build_query)?

Answer (score 0):

Try [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
<?php

$str = "?customerID=12345&recid=65&skip=20&type=job";
$newStr = preg_replace_callback("/skip=([0-9]+)/i", "doIt", $str)

function doIt($match){

  return $match[1] + 20;

}
```